# Can't setState (reactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using jquery todo onClick

```
$('.month').on('click', (e) => {
    let date = $("#myMonthPicker").val();

    this.setState({bbb:date});
  });
```

get error bbb is not defined. How to make right bind?

Comment: why are you using jquery + react?

Comment: missing `{}`, `this.setState({bbb:date});` as well as use arrow function: `$('.month').on('click',  (e) => {`

Comment: not helps, this.setState({bbb:date});

Comment: check the above comment use `arrow function` for `context`, but i will suggest you to not use `query` with `react`, you should avoid direct `dom interaction`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function when using arrow func

Comment: problem solved, I remove document ready func

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко if your problem is solved then answer your own question instead of comment